# Find $\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln(n^{n}\cdot(n+1)^{-n-1})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, limits, logarithms

I have to solve this limit:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln(n^{n}\cdot(n+1)^{-n-1})$$
I know the answer is $-\infty$. My question is, can I do this:
$$\ln[\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{n}\cdot(n+1)^{-n-1}]$$
If not, how should I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The natural logarithm is continuous on its domain, so you can do that, but I don't recommend it. Another approach is to rewrite the natural logarithm as
$$\ln(n^n\cdot(n+1)^{-n-1})=n\ln(n)-(n+1)\ln(n+1).$$
Then the result follows from the fact that the natural logarithm increases strictly  to infinity.

Comment: How do you resolve the indetermination?

Comment: My last line hints at the fact that $\ln(n)<\ln(n+1)$, and hence that
$$n\ln(n)-(n+1)\ln(n+1)<-\ln(n+1),$$
where the right hand side tends to negative infinity.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't see. Hence that what?

Comment: OK. I think you should add some details to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have
$$
\ln(n^{n}\cdot(n+1)^{-n-1})=n\,\ln \frac n{n+1}-\ln(n+1)<-\ln(n+1).
$$

As for your question, you can "take out" the log if the limit exists, because the log is continuous.

Comment: How did you get that last equality.

Comment: That last equality is false.

Comment: Yes, my bad. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that works. The inner limit is at the edge of the domain for $\log$ however.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{(1+\frac 1n)^n \cdot (n+1)} = 0$$

Now just take the logarithm and use the fact that the natural logarithm is a continuous function.